# Is there an advantage to using jQuery's $().on('mouseenter',function(){}) over $().mouseenter(function(){})?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I frequently see code like:

```
$("#thing").on("mouseenter",function(){ Do stuff });
```

Personally, I almost always write:

```
$("#thing").mouseenter(function(){ Do stuff });
```

Similarly, I often write

```
$("#thing").click(function(){})
```

but I have seen people correct it to (yes, I know `on` is preferred over `bind` in v. 1.7+, so it's essentially the same preference issue):

```
$("#thing").bind("click",function(){})
```

Am I doing something "wrong", is there a deep difference between the two functions that I'm not seeing? It always seems to do what I want it to do, so it's never been a practical concern, but I'd be interested to know if there's a theoretical consideration I'm overlooking.

Comment: There is no functional difference between the two, the performance difference is also negligible. One difference that IS important (in my opinion) is keeping the code consistent. If the existing code uses `.on` throughout rather than the shorthand, keep using `.on`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really, it's just a little faster as the `mouseenter` function calls `on` (or `trigger` if called without argument) as can be seen in the source code :

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
});
```

As you can see, the same can be said for many events.

Personally, I prefer to use the `mouseenter` (or `click`, etc.) function when I don't need the special features of `on` : one of the big advantages in my opinion in using jQuery is that it makes the code less verbose and more readable. And I don't think you should be corrected, ask the guys who corrects you why he does that.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the specific events like `.click` or `$.post` are shortcuts.  They act the same as using the `.on` and `$.ajax` functions but the latter normally have greater flexibility.  EG `.on` can bind to multiple event while `.click` only subscribes to clicks.  Same applies to the `$.ajax` function, there are more options where as the shortcuts have certain defaults set.

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical difference between the two, the shorthand functions (`.click()`, `.mouseover()`, etc) call `.on()` to actually bind the event handler anyway. The only "advantage" to using `.on()` directly is that you don't have the additional overhead of a second function call; I suspect that's likely to be marginal enough that it's a very premature optimisation though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not neccessarily wrong, but on has its advantages over the normal way.

By "binding" the event to your parent container `$(parent).on(event, target, function() { //foobar });` you are able to add new target elements into your container, while not having to repeat the jquery to bind the event.

Comment: Technically true, but we're not discussing direct vs delegated events here. We're comparing direct events using `.click()` (for example) vs direct events using `.on('click')`.

Comment: I think OP voluntary was explicit to avoid the special case where a target is added. This answer seems off-topic.

Comment: @dystroy I hadn't foreseen adding elements, to be fair, but the source code indicates that `.click()` calls `.on("click"...)` so shouldn't they behave the same even in that case?

Comment: It only binds the click event to the current dom. By binding the event to the parent, with a defined target, it will allow the event to be ran on new child elements aswel.

Comment: @JasonNichols I don't get your comment. Did you read my answer ? If so, can you be more precise ?

Comment: @StefanCandan can you elaborate? I'm almost there, but I'm still a little confused... Basically you're saying the `null` in the `.on()` call in the definition of `.click()` prevents me from doing `$(parent).click("target", function(){})`? thanks for the additional insight, trying to get a deeper understanding.

Comment: @dystroy totally read your answer. Incredibly informative. Was going to upvote, but until my question got upvoted, didn't have enough rep to. I just didn't want credit where it wasn't due. I wasn't smart enough to intentionally preclude adding elements to the DOM in my question. If I did, it was accidental at best.

Comment: @JasonNichols Basically yes, If you look at this little fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/k59ku/) you can see how the newly added element in the static div doesn't add a new one if you click on it, but in the dynamic one it does add a new one.